# Diferencias entre Vue.js, Vue Cli, y Vue Laravel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Por que son tan diferentes la forma que se integra Vue en un proyecto?
El tutorial basico de la documentacion de Vue ese colocar el script dentro del head del archivo `.html` y en otro script tener lo siguiente:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    estado: 'Critico'
  }
})
```

mientras que cuando creo un proyecto con Vue Cli
El archivo `main.js` tiene lo siguiente:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
new Vue({
 el:'#app',
 render: h => h(App)
})
```

Y con laravel el codigo del archivo `app.js` es:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

y el archivo `bootstrap.js` que parece añadir extras como vue axios:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Y me surgen muchas preguntas.
Porque desaparece la propiedad `render:` de la tercera instancia que se muestra?

Porque la segunda usa `import` mientras que la tercera usa `require`? Ambas trabajan con Node, no?

Porque la primera linea del archivo `bootstrap.js` se asigna un `require('lodash')` al atributo `_`

Que recomiendan aprender antes de seguir avanzando con Vue? Se algo de javascript basico por que me recomendaron aprender Vanilla JS antes de usar cualquier framework, pero ver el archivo `bootstrap.js` con `window.$`, asignandole un valor y que a este ultimo, tambien se le asigne otro valor en la misma linea. Me confundio bastante.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vue te permite trabajar con el como:

**Opción 1**

Dependencia de un proyecto e incluirlo de forma tradicional como lo hacías con JQuery, es decir lo invocas al final de tu documento HTML por medio de la etiqueta `script` a través del atributo `src`.

Para el caso anterior solo estás requiriendo a Vue como un complemento de trabajo en un proyecto nuevo o ya existente en *X* lenguaje o *X* framework.

- En este caso como puedes estar invocando al script desde local o a través de su CDN no requieres de una instalación de NodeJS para su uso

Donde la sintaxis a manejar será la siguiente:

```
new Vue({
    el: `#escenario`,
    data: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    }
})
```

**Opción 2**

Vue CLI, te permite crear un proyecto donde Vue puede trabajar como el frontend completo y el lenguaje en uso en esta parte sea enteramente JavaScript, donde buscamos solo consumir la data que generen determinados *endpoints* de un proyecto en *X* lenguaje o framework.

Aquí ya se genera una de las primera diferencias, que es:

- Vue va a requerir que el ambiente en el que estés trabajando posea una instalación de NodeJS para que la instalación y ejecución de tu proyecto funcione.
- Los componentes están en la ruta: `appname/src/components`
- Los componentes son archivos con extensión `.vue`
- Los componentes se les conoce como **Single File Component**
- Se componen de 3 secciones: `template`, `script` y `style`
- Requiere que hagas uso de [SSR](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html)
- Para este segundo escenario, esta sintaxis es la que invoca a Vue:

Código

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

Hace referencia a la sintaxis de los [módulos](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_introduction) en NodeJS

> Las funciones escritas en JS, se pueden exportar desde un script específico e importarlas desde un módulo o script diferente

*Actualización*

> Dentro de esta opción, se hace la aclaración que estoy exponiendo el proceso que se recomienda por parte del equipo de Vue, pues da un boilerplate base y listo para iniciar un proyecto, sin embargo no es obligatorio seguir esta convención y se puede construir todo incluyendo su estructura *(del proyecto)* desde cero.

**Opción 3**

En el caso de Laravel, recordar que para su uso de webpack, el cuenta con [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix) que apuntará a `app.js` como el archivo destino donde todos los scripts compilarán y almacenarán el resultado de dicha acción.

Aunque técnicamente en Laravel pudieras incluir a Vue como un llamado clásico a través de:

```
<script src="rutadevue"></script>
```

Laravel te brinda la oportunidad de requerirlo a través de NodeJS, ya que en la carpeta principal del proyecto puedes encontrar un *package.json* donde ya viene declarado Vue como una dependencia, que podrás usar en tanto:

- Ejecutes el comando `npm install`
- Puedas contar con una instalación de NodeJS

Dicho lo anterior, en Laravel:

- Creas los componentes en `myapp/resources/js/components`
- Lo registras en: `app/resources/myapp.js`

Con esta sintaxis:

```
Vue.component('listado', require('./components/listado.vue').default)
```

Aquí es donde `laravel mix` nos simplifica la tarea, por que puedes compilar tanto en desarrollo como en producción para reducir el tamaño de los archivos de salida con estos [dos comandos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix):

```
npm run dev

npm run production
```

Al final para poder acceder a tus componentes a diferencia de un proyecto hecho con Vue-CLI, aquí solo necesitas invocar en la vista por medio del helper `asset()` al archivo app.js de este modo:

```
<script src="{{ asset('app.js') }}"></script>
```

Y ya en la vista podrás hacer uso de tu componente así:

```
<listado></listado>
```

Para el caso de los *extras* que mencionas no lo son en realidad; recordar que:

- *axios* es una librería basada en promesas para hacer peticiones AJAX **que perfectamente puede ser sustituida por el uso de la API nativa `fetch` que también se basa en promesas**
- Puedes perfectamente incluir esta misma *(axios)* en un proyecto realizado con VueCLI; de hecho cuando estás instalando una copia nueva con esta opción te indica la posibilidad de requerir el uso de dicha biblioteca.
- Si no deseas hacer uso de *axios* puedes prescindir de este mismo y quitarlo del mismo *package.json* para que no se instale cuando ejecutes el comando de `npm install`

Con respecto a: `import` y `require`

- [`Require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) sigue la sintaxis básica de [commonJS](https://nodejs.org/zh-cn/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) la cual considera estos pasos:

  - Leer un archivo *JavaScript*
  - Ejecutar el archivo
  - Retornar el objeto exportado
- [`Import/Export`] *Revisar el enlace propuesto más arriba*

Una diferencia tal vez muy grande, es que si incluyes a Vue en tun proyecto con la sintaxis tradicional de:

```
<script src="rutadeVue"></script>
```

El modo en el que trabajarás los componentes sea de este modo:

```
Vue.component('mi-listado', {
    props: ['saludo'],
    template: `
                <h1>Hola a {{ saludo }}</h1>
              `
})
```

Lo anterior depende de la instancia de Vue creada y del valor de la propiedad `saludo` en el objeto `data`

```
new Vue({
   el: `#seccion`,
   data: {
       saludo: 'Hola SO'
   }
})
```

Mientras que si trabajas tanto con la opción 2 o 3 vas a manejarte a través de los denominados `single file components` que tienen las siguientes características:

- Tienen una etiqueta de apertura y cierre así: `<template></template>`
- Poseen una extensión `.vue`
- Poseen 3 secciones principales así:

Sintaxis

```
<template>
   <div>
  
   </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

**Referencias**

- De lo anterior puedes [leer aquí](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) mas al respecto
- Con respecto a la propiedad [render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)?
- Con respecto a tu última pregunta, tu mismo te has respondido debes aprender JavaScript

Comment: Excelente respuesta.. pero la opcion 2 es incorrecta. Por ejemplo si incluyes TS, algunos de tus archivos van a tener extension ts. Ni siquiera necesitas el cli para crear un proyecto, y las rutas las decidis vos.

Comment: @gbianchi te agradezco la observación, como no uso TS no me detuve a pensar en ese detalle, respecto al resto que mencionas me guié entereamente por la estructura que brinda el cli, pero... ciertamente tienes razón en todo lo que mencionas

Comment: Recomendaria agregar que la opcion dos son las mejores practicas recomendadas por la gente vue. Y permite generar un proyecto spa de cero sin necesidad de incluir a mano cada paquete, ya que genera un proyecto listo para ser ejecutado. Sin embrago, no es obligatorio y se puede hacer todo a mano.

Comment: Sigo tu recomendación y espero como lo redacté sea funcional @gbianchi

Comment: Es muy bueno ver algo así de completo y que no se va por las ramas!